# How to get value when I click move/remove on duallist button - JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to get **single value** not **all selected value** on the duallistbox, this is what I've tried so far

```
$(document).on("click", ".move", function(){
    alert( $(".agentItems").val() )
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
    alert( $(".agentItems").val() )
});
```

but I want a single value based on the option he select on (move/remove) so If I want to move `One, wand`, I will get `<option value="1">One, Wand</option>` or `1` on `alert()` not all **selected**

[image]

this is the **JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/sdxaV/19/

and this is the DUALLISTBOX I've used : http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

**EDIT 1**

Test my jsfiddle, try to move `One, wand` then you will get value `1,2,4` instead `1`, Please need help how to get the value that moved.

Answer (score 1):

got it using this, thanks to @GNi33,
here it is http://jsfiddle.net/sdxaV/26/

```
var result = $(".agentItems").val();

console.log(result);

$(document).on("click", ".move", function(){
    var diff = arr_diff(result, $(".agentItems").val());

  console.log(diff);

  result = $(".agentItems").val();
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
  var diff = arr_diff(result, $(".agentItems").val());

  console.log(diff);
  result = $(".agentItems").val();
});


function arr_diff (a1, a2) {

        a1 = a1 || [];
    a2 = a2 || [];

    var a = [], diff = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = true;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (a[a2[i]]) {
            delete a[a2[i]];
        } else {
            a[a2[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    for (var k in a) {
        diff.push(k);
    }

    return diff;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your fiddle and on this line

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="agentItems" class="agentItems">
```

you set your select multiple. Try deleting it and you should be fine.

Update:
I Changed your fiddle and addedn that commended line where you should change. it will get you the latest select. Dont change html that i stated before.

```
$(document).on("click", ".move", function(){
    var latest_value = $("option:selected:last").val();
    alert( latest_value )//option:selected:last will give you latest value of select so you can use it according to your need
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(){
    var latest_value = $("option:selected:last").val();
    alert( latest_value )//same goes here
});
```

Comment: tried it but it only select one option, or it delete past selected to a new one

Comment: isn't that what you are trying to achieve? i guess i got you wrong then, sorry about that. can you tell me what exactly it should do? i'll be glad to help you out.

Comment: I want to get the data passed so I can used it on AJAX and PHP SQL insert, I don't want to reinsert/delete it again, so when I click that button `move` I will get the value of that moved item.

Comment: yo bro, got it already. here: http://jsfiddle.net/sdxaV/26/ on your .remove it still shows all value

Comment: Ah, i only changed the move part, to check if i was on the right path for you :). anyway you got it